# what is this red dot?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I don't know what I did. There is a red dot or square on my blender. whatever I move or rotate my space. This red thing just stable in my space.

Comment: I was noticing something like that in BLUE the other day with Blender 3.0 but didn't dig in to figure out what it was.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a tiny mesh. maibe it is linked to your camera. See if it is still there if you delete meshes or if you go to edit mode. could also be some kind of glitch i am not aware of.